# HBase without using HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, deduplication

I am doing a little research project and I am thinking about using HBase for it. I have read in the quick start guide that HBase can be set up using the local file system. I was reading this guy's paper: http://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=9879&context=infopapers

And it makes me wonder if you could use HBase with SDFS (from the opendedup project) to get fast indexing into a file system deduped at the block level? I.E. Dedup first based on unique key to insert into hbase, and have it on top of SDFS for deduplication at the local file system level.

Would this work, or am I way off base?

Comment: What exactly is your usecase?

Comment: Similar to what the paper describes, except I would be interested in using SDFS to reduce file storage requirements on the disk local to the hbase install, not distributed